# NLS settings for specific date/time format

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, datestamp

I want my query output in Oracle sql developer in this format:

> Fri Oct 18 21:45:14 AEDT 2019

How can I change the NLS settings accordingly?

This is the current format that I get now:

> Saturday  Dec 21 09:10:29

by using the format:

```
Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your format by doing the following for EST:

```
select to_char(systimestamp at time zone 'EST', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') 
from dual;
```

**Output**: Thu Dec 26 12:52:38 EST 2019

If AEDT is not configured in your database you may receive a ORA-01882 error "timezone region not found".